# Update HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function that is attempting to filter data based on what is in the `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString`. A recent "improvement" has changed how I have to filter what's being shown. Now I need to update the `QueryString` before my filtering functions run. Based on some other StackOverflow questions I have tried a few different ways but they haven't work.

```
    var queryString = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString;
    var nameValues = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString( queryString.ToString() );
    nameValues.Add( "IsDeleted", "False" );
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath;
    string updatedQuerySring = "?" + nameValues.ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect( url + updatedQuerySring );
```

The above threw a system.Web.HttpException error "Server cannot set status after HTTP headers have been sent."

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Add( "IsDeleted", "False" );
```

and

```
    NameValueCollection newQuery = new NameValueCollection();
    foreach( var key in queryString.Keys ){
        var value = queryString[ key.ToString()];
        newQuery.Add( key.ToString(), value );
    }
    newQuery.Add( "IsDeleted", "False" );
    HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString = newQuery;
```

both come up with "Error    20  Property or indexer 'System.Web.HttpRequest.QueryString' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only". How do you update the `QueryString` so that I can add the `IsDeleted` filter it?

*EDIT* it was suggested to keep it in a session or tempdata variable but that won't work as it is needed in more than 1 redirect.

Comment: You cannot change the current request, you can create a new request and add your queryString to the new request

Comment: @Ziv I was afraid of that. The filter function was further down than I wanted to pass a queryString but if that's what has to be done then so be it. Thank you.

Comment: Actually there is no good way to fix it. Is there is something missing for you in request query string -> do not  change it. Construct your own string(based on query string) and use it in filtering. A bad way, but have you tried url rewriting?

Comment: If you need to just know if "IsDeleted" you can keep that var in Session or TempData (which only 'survives' one redirect)

Answer (score 3):

You need to make `httpcontenxt.current` readonly property to `false` and assign parameters now.

```
PropertyInfo isreadonly = typeof(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection).GetProperty("IsReadOnly", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
isreadonly.SetValue(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString, false, null);                
HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString.Set(key, value);                
isreadonly.SetValue(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString, true, null);
```

Comment: In my case i used it for HttpContext.Current.Request.Param and worked like a charm, thanks